# return to default language after Google ad close

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I have two activity when I click button on first show Google ad, when I close ad the second activity start.
The problem is the first activity in Arabic language but after close Google ad second activity return to English.
(This problem haven't if I remove Google ad)
Thank you.

Comment: Is your activity changing locale from Arabic to English due to Google Ad somehow and you want to avoid it. Is that your question?

Comment: No, only the language of the second activity changes to the default language

Comment: Have you tried adding android:configChanges="locale" in your manifest for second activity it'll override any configuration change. It might help